# How css grid computes row auto height?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the below snippet, I can not understand how `.cell1`(orange) height has been computed. Why it is so high? Why it is higher than right column content? How left cells height depends on right column and it's contains height?

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 62px auto;
  background: beige;
}

.cell1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background: salmon; 
}

.cell2 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  background: MediumSpringGreen; 
}

.cell3 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background: PeachPuff; 
}

.cell3-1 {
  background: MediumPurple;
  height: 5px;
}

.cell3-2 {
  background: LightSkyBlue;
  height: 10px;
}

.cell3-3 {
  background: Navy;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="cell1">1</div>
  <div class="cell2">2</div>
  <div class="cell3">
    <div class="cell3-1"></div>
    <div class="cell3-2"></div>
    <div class="cell3-3"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Seems that you `cell1` is getting the `62px height` from your
`header{  grid-template-rows: 62px auto;}`

Comment: @Matt Oh... I completely forgot to remove 62px after experiments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your title.

> How css grid computes row auto height?

`auto` just means it adapts to the height of the content within it. If the content in an `auto` row, is 100px tall, the row will be 100px tall.

> I can not understand how .cell1(orange) height has been computed. Why it is so high?

Because you have told the **first** row to be 62px tall here:

```
  grid-template-rows: 62px auto;
```

> Why it is higher than right column content?

It isn't...but I can see that you might think that.

> > How left cells height depends on right column and it's contains height?

The right content **in the context of the grid** is **only** the `.cell-3` div **but** you have told div to span 2 rows. So it assumes the *combined* height of `.cell-` and `.cell-2`.

The content **inside** `cell-3` does not inherit any of the grid properties and so flows as normal.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Oh... I completely forgot to remove `62px` after experiments...